# Cannot access home route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

When trying to access localhost:3000/static_pages/home I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#home

/Users/user/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
Rails.root: /Users/user/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

routes.rb contents:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "static_pages/home"

  get "static_pages/help"

  get "static_pages/about"

  get "static_pages/contact"

end
```

application_helper.rb contents:

```
def full_title(page_title)
base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
if page_title.empty?
base_title
else
"#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
end
end
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb contents:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `application_helper.rb` seems to be broken. You probably want something like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end

end
```

Seems the `module` line got missing. That's why Ruby is complaining about an additional `end` in the last line.